# How does the Windows 10 Store "Downloads and Installs" page work?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

When you disable automatic app updates in the Windows 10 Store, you can access the list of available updates by clicking the "pending update count" icon in the top banner next to your profile icon.  This accesses a screen that looks like the following:

[image: update screen]

The icons at the right-hand of the matrix becomes outlined as the mouse cursor moves over them, suggesting that they are clickable, but clicking has no discernible effect (for either the download-with-slash or the trashcan).

What do the icons mean and how can individual updates be applied?

Also, it would be nice to know why some updates list the size and some do not.

Comment: I have automatic updates enabled, and so I don't see the icons.  A)  When you hover your mouse over them, is there any hover text?  B)  Did you try a TinEye or Google reverse image search for the icons?

Comment: @unforgettableid: No, no hover text.  Tooltops aren't really standard UI for Universal Windows UI apps.  However, it does look like one of the major updates (service pack-equivalent) has changed the icon appearance.